# How to parse optional flags regardless of their position in script call and number of repetitions?

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, unix, sh

I am writing a BASH script called *stat* which needs to parse its arguments in a way that it catches repetitions and different positions.
The script can be called without any arguments, with an optional flag *-r* and optional filename also passed to the script as an argument, in this example *directory1*.

How can I parse the arguments so the following script calls are valid?

```
./stat
./stat -r
./stat directory1
./stat -r directory1
./stat directory1 -r
./stat directory1 -r -r
./stat -r directory1 -r
```

So far, I have a way to parse *./stat -r directory1*.

```
recursive=0
while getopts ":r" opt; do
case $opt in
    r)
        recursive=1 
    ;;
    *)
                    echo "-$0: $opt is not a valid argument!"
        exit 1
    ;;
esac
done
```

This leaves me with parsing the directory name, which outputs only the directory name.

```
shift $((OPTIND-1)) #which removes processed options
echo "$*"
```

However, if I call the script with *./stat directory1 -r*, *./stat -r directory1 -r* or *./stat directory1 -r -r*, the arguments are not properly parsed as the *-r* flag following the directory name is left out, not parsed and not removed with the *shift $((OPTIND-1))* call.

So, I would like to know, how I can parse option flags so even redundant ones are captured along with the ones that may follow *directory1*.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've found, `getopts` stops at the first non-option word. You're forced to iterate over all the arguments:

```
dir="some default"
recursive=false
for arg; do
    if [[ $arg == "-r" ]]; then
        recursive=true
    else
        dir=$arg
    fi
done
```

An advantage to using "true" and "false" like this is you can then write this, since `true` and `false` are programs on the $PATH:

```
if $recursive; then
    do_something_repeatedly
else
    do_something_once
fi
```

---

Checking for invalid options:

```
for arg; do
    case $arg in
        -r) recursive=true ;;
        -*) echo "invalid option: $arg" ;;
        *)  dir=$arg ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: I see, so inside the _if [[ $arg == "-r" ]]; then_ clause, instead of checking directly if the argument is *-r*, could I test it with regex like this _if [ $arg == ^-. ]_ to see if an argument is exactly one dash followed by a single letter as to validate the *-r* flag and throw an error in case of any other flag?

Comment: The `true` and `false` that are going to be executed are not the commands in `PATH` (i.e., `/bin/true` or `/bin/false`) but the _builtins_ `true` and `false`.

Comment: Ah, I was unaware that they were builtin. Learned.